# Opening include files from org-mode

Tags: org-mode

In org mode, a file can be included for export using `#+Include: filename`.  Is there an easy way to open a file in an include statement?
I've tried <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>, but emacs states "no link found".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a command called `org-edit-src-exit` in org-mode, which can open source block in a new buffer of itself major mode, and open **Include file**.

This command is binded with `C-c '` in default.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer a little more.

Comment: Same as editing source blocks, I'm not sure why I didn't think to try that.

Comment: Although, `org-edit-special` which is usually bound to `C-c '` does not respect the `:lines` parameter which is ubiquitous in `org-mode`'s `#+INCLUDE`. That is, when you do `org-edit-special` you will always end up at the beginning of the file or at the point you left your cursor.

Answer (score 8):

There exists a generic solution not limited to `org-mode`:

`M-x ffap` (alias of `find-file-at-point`) does exactly what it sounds like it does.

`helm-find-files` also automatically populates the minibuffer with the filename at the point if one exists.

Use one of these commands and then hit return to visit the file under the point.